# Bridgeland stability conditions: proving continuity of $\log \frac{m_{\sigma_2}(E)}{m_{\sigma_1}(E)}$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, vector-bundles

I am reading [Stability Conditions on Triangulated Categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212237.pdf) Prop. 8.1. When Bridgeland proves the continuity of $\log \frac{m_{\sigma_2}(E)}{m_{\sigma_1}(E)}$ he says:

> But now one can choose $\phi$ so that
> $$\sum_k m_\sigma(\beta_k(E))\leq\left(1+\frac2n\right)m_\sigma(E)$$

Why is this true? I think that the $\left(1+\dfrac2n\right)$ factor could be the ratio between the length of the two intervals $I_k$ and $J_k$ defined a few lines before, but why is it related? Also, why is it related to the choice of $\phi$?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $\beta_k$?

Comment: @Sasha truncation functor projecting to subcategory P(Jk), defined at the bottom of p.25 of the pdf